# Has there been any custom roms ported for the ZTE Score?

Tags: custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I've been keeping an eye on CWM and CM7 for the past few months.. And now I'm slowly but surely giving up hope on ever finding a custom rom for the ZTE Score, aka ZTE X500.
  I'll most likely keep an eye out for awhile longer; but I'm curious if there will ever be one. Anyway, has anyone heard any news that I may have missed? Custom/Stock Roms?

Comment: See this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device/17153#17153